# can't install python lxml library

Tags: python, windows, pip, lxml

I have a problem with installing lxml library for python. I tried to install using pip and got this problem:

[image: problem]

Comment: errors and warning are in russian (or a cyrilic language), not useful for resolve.

Comment: nothing useful in it, it basically just says "here is the error", then the actual message is in English.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can download prebuilt lxml from here:
```

[lxml](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml)